# How can I create a delegate in F# of the type System.Buffers.SpanAction for use in String.Create?

Tags: f#, delegates

This question was also asked on F# Slack, but since that's not visible to the wider community, and since I don't have a solution yet, I figured it made sense to ask it here.

Basically, `String.Create` works with `Span` to create a new string and takes a delegate to fill the span. This is generally faster than changing a string the normal way: create a `char` array, call `AsSpan`, and calling the proper `String` constructor with the result.

This works fine:

```
let create value = 
    String.Create(12, value, fun buf v-> 
        for i = 0 to buf.Length do
            buf.[i] <- v)
```

But the minute I try to use a function that's curried, or try to use a delegate, I get a type error. According to F#, the delegate is of type `SpanAction<'T, 'TArg>`, where `'T` translates to `Span<'T>` in the callback, and `'TArg` is any argument you can use to prevent a closure.

I've tried several variants, but all come down to this basic idea:

```
type SpanDelegate<'T, 'TArg> = delegate of Span<'T> * 'TArg -> unit

let callback = 
    new SpanDelegate<char, char>(fun buf v -> 
      for i = 0 to buf.Length do buf.[i] <- v)

let create (value: char) = 
    String.Create(12, value, callback)   // type error on callback
```

Whether or not I use it with the original lambda, I can't seem to get it to work. Ideas are welcome :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your code does not work is that you are creating a custom delegate `SpanDelegate`, but the code expects a pre-defined delegate `SpanAction`.

I'm not exactly sure I understand your issue correct (and so I may be missing something), but if you create the pre-defined `SpanAction` delegate, then everything seems to be working fine:

```
open System
open System.Buffers

let callback = 
    SpanAction<char, char>(fun buf v -> 
      for i = 0 to buf.Length do buf.[i] <- v)

let create (value: char) = 
    String.Create(12, value, callback)
```

Comment: Hi Thomas, nice seeing you here, was a great conference! I thought it was a type alias of a delegate, which is a strange thought considering I checked the C# sources. Still interesting that it's inferred from a lambda, but not from a curried function. Thanks, just needed your clear head!

Comment: Actually, thinking about it a second more, while it's a predefined delegate, don't delegates work such that if you create a delegate of the same type (same arguments and return value), that they are interchangeable (meaning: where a delegate with such signature is expected, any delegate with the same signature can be used)?

Comment: This is the weird thing about delegates (from a functional programmer's perspective) - if you have two delegates that have the same argument and return types, they are not actually treated as the same thing! This is why your approach with `SpanDelegate` did not work. What F# does in the first cases (your snippet that worked) is that it implicitly converted a lambda from an F# function to a delegate - but this only happens in limited cases (basically, whenever you use a lambda as an argument to a method).

Comment: Thanks, that clears it up. Possibly, this lang suggestion could make life easier, if it does what I think it does: https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/878